# I want to perfect my controller-view interaction when i have multiple sets of data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, design-patterns, view, controller

I feel the controller->view interaction miss something, so here is my question.

I have a controller action that is generating a bunch of data :

@first
@second
@third

Each variable is displayed in the view to one html block (partials).

Sometime one or more of these will be empty and i still want to display the other ones.

My solution to address this problem, is to set the variable to a string ("no data") in the controller, as usually the data is some kind of array, i test for string in the view to check if there is real data and respond accordingly.

On top of that, i also have use cases where my data will not always be displayed with the same partial. I know I can do it with a few conditions before calling the correct partial.

A good example of the kind of problem i have in mind would be a Dashboard where some items are sometimes missing or changing depending of the data displayed.

I am already making these use case working, but it feels that I am not doing MVC correctly by putting to much logic inside the view. Is there a better design pattern, rails specific or not, to address this situation?

Answer (score 0):

you can check value present or not using present? in MVC.

In your controller/view check this condition.

```
if @first.present?
  do somthing
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any serious problem with your approach. You have some logic that determines details of how the data is displayed. You cannot escape this. The only question is where this logic should go (it cannot go away, alas). I think putting it in the View is the best decision.

However I recommend making the interface between the Controller and the View as explicit as possible. Setting a variable to nil is clearer than setting it to "no data". You may need to add more variables to your Model so that the View knows what to do. This is better than having e.g. a variable that is usually an array but sometimes holds a string that tells the View how to display the data.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a job for the [Draper](https://github.com/jcasimir/draper)

Draper inserts a `View-Model` into the MVC mix which sits between Controller and View and decorates a model, handling all custom view-logic in an object-oriented way while keeping it separate both from view and model layers.

Take a look at the [RailsCast on Draper](http://railscasts.com/episodes/286-draper) for example. Pretty nice (and logical if you think of it).